# Define an SVG in the HTML but use it like it was included directly in the CSS via background-image with url

Tags: html, css, svg

I would like to obtain the same result as the following snippet, but with the SVG being defined/included in the HTML file instead of in CSS, so that I can keep the CSS independent from the specific content of the web page.

```css
.image {
  content: "";
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/03/Flag_of_Italy.svg");
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="image"></div>
```

I've not been able to do it myself, because as soon as put the SVG in the HTML, then I have to target it and write CSS rules for it, whereas when it is in the CSS as in the snippet above, it is *part of* the rule, so it's two completely different workflows.

Comment: You can set styles directly on the element itself like this `<span style="color: red;">Hello</span>`. More info here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/style

Comment: Maybe what you're looking for is a [data URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) but on the whole I find the question unclear.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use an `<svg>` tag, give it an `id="image"` attribute, and refer to it via `background-image: url(#image)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it with CSS variables.  Like so:

```css
.image {
  content: "";
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-image: var(--bg);
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="image" style="--bg: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/03/Flag_of_Italy.svg)" ></div>
```

Although perhaps you are just happy with making the `.image` CSS rule non-specific, by separating out the icon into a different class.  This is a very common technique in CSS.

```css
.image {
  content: "";
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-size: 100%;
}

.flag-it {
  background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/03/Flag_of_Italy.svg);
}
```

```html
<div class="image flag-it"></div>
```

Then define other versions of the `flag-it` CSS rule for other flags.

Comment: +1. Would you say there's an easy way to make the first approach work if the tag is not `div` but `label`? I've tried, but no luck, so I was thinking to ask another question... Just to avoid being OT.

Comment: @Enlico A `label` will be inline by default. So you would need to make it `display: block` or `display: inline-block` in order to set the width, height, and background. See https://jsfiddle.net/2ktg5r3m/

Comment: As regard your answer (not your last comment), if you try using the [uk flag](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/ae/Flag_of_the_United_Kingdom.svg) you'll see a quirk which is not apparent with the italian flag. Can that be fixed somehow? (That affects also the solution in the link from your last comment, incidentally.)

Comment: The design of the Italian flag means that you don't notice that it is repeated vertically. Which is what is happening here. Because the flag icons are not square, the images are getting repeated. Unfortunately, SVGs are special in that they have special scaling rules that are different from other types of images.  To get these SVGs to stretch how you want (presumably) you would need to modify them slightly. Add the attribute `preserveAspectRatio="none"` to the opening `<svg>` tag.